# How can I search for a specific attachment in outlook

Tags: c#

I am trying to retrieve a specific attachment in Outlook to save to my folder.
Everything works great but it seems to save all the attachments in the "Inbox" Folder instead of the specific one I am looking for.

This is what I have at the moment:

```
static void EnumerateFoldersInDefaultStore()
    {
        Outlook.Application Application = new Outlook.Application();
        Outlook.Folder root = Application.Session.DefaultStore.GetRootFolder() as Outlook.Folder;
        EnumerateFolders(root);
    }

    static void EnumerateFolders(Outlook.Folder folder)
    {
        Outlook.Folders childFolders = folder.Folders;
        if (childFolders.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (Outlook.Folder childFolder in childFolders)
            {
                if (childFolder.FolderPath.Contains("Inbox"))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(childFolder.FolderPath);
                    EnumerateFolders(childFolder);
                }
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Checking in " + folder.FolderPath);
        IterateMessages(folder);
    }

    static void IterateMessages(Outlook.Folder folder)
    {
        string fileName = "Reports.pdf";

        var fi = folder.Items;
        if (fi != null)
        {
            try
            {
                foreach (Object item in fi)
                {
                    Outlook.MailItem mi = (Outlook.MailItem)item;
                    var attachments = mi.Attachments;
                    if (attachments.Count != 0)
                    {
                        if (!Directory.Exists(basePath + folder.FolderPath))
                        {
                            Directory.CreateDirectory(basePath + folder.FolderPath);
                        }

                        for (int i = 1; i <= mi.Attachments.Count; i++)
                        {
                            if (fileName != null)
                            {
                                if (!Directory.Exists(basePath))
                                {
                                    Directory.CreateDirectory(basePath);
                                }
                                totalfilesize = totalfilesize + mi.Attachments[i].Size;
                                if (!File.Exists(basePath + mi.Attachments[i].FileName))
                                {
                                    Console.WriteLine("Saving " + mi.Attachments[i].FileName);
                                    mi.Attachments[i].SaveAsFile(basePath + mi.Attachments[i].FileName);
                                }

                                else
                                {
                                    Console.WriteLine("Already saved " + mi.Attachments[i].FileName);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("An error occurred: '{0}'", e);
            }
        }
    }
```

So it basically searches the entire "Inbox" and saves all the attachments but like I said not the one I want only - "Reports.pdf"

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: `if (mi.Attachments[i].FileName == fileName) { // save file` ?

Comment: WOW! that was simple thanks!! How did i miss that? Thanks it is working perfectly now!!!

Answer (score 0):

In `static void IterateMessages(Outlook.Folder folder)` you currently only check for `if (fileName != null)` (which should never happen as fileName is always assigned at the beginning of the method).

You need to add a condition to check if the attached file meets your fileName-Criteria, e.g.:

```cs
if (mi.Attachments[i].FileName == fileName) {
  //Save your attachment
} else {
  // naming-critera not met, skip...
}
```